# Kalman filter - Measurement and process noise

Tags: kalman-filter

I am curious about measurement noise when we run Kalman filter update at different rate, do we have to scale measurement noise based on delta time between updates ?
For example if I run Kalman filter at 20 Hz vs 25 Hz with same measurement matrix, I tend to get quite different results because we are using updating more in 2nd case and cause error co-variance matrix value smaller than first one. 
For example if I have velocity measurement with 2 m/s error at 20 Hz rate, do I need to scale measurement noise by delta time (0.05 s) ?
For process noise, we scale based on time interval but I am not sure about measurement noise.

Answer (score 1):

If the measurements are **independent**, the covariance matrix values **should** be smaller for 25 Hz updates vs 20Hz updates because you have more measurements.

It might be that your measurements are not independent, e.g. if there is one new velocity measurement every second and you apply it 20 or 25 times in a measurement update. In such a case, I would do a measurement update every second and a time update (propagation/prediction) at 20 or 25 Hz. Most text books use the same frequency for both updates, but it is perfectly fine to do them at different rates.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I am trying to estimate gravity vector using accelerometer and motion is dynamic which introducing some acceleration in accelerometer measurements. All acceleratometer measurements are sampled directly from sensor at 25 Hz but acceleration  is highly correlated because of motion. I am treating acceleration as noise here. Even if I compute correct measurement noise (additional acceleation due to motion), it is not performing well.